# Selenium Testing For Element Existence Failure

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Back again with another Selenium question!...

Here is what I have so far

```
public static void mobileAssessmentPage() {
    List<WebElement> elements = SeleniumCommands.findElementsByCss(ASSESSMENTANSWER);
    List<WebElement> pageTitle;

    for (WebElement element : elements) element.click();

    SeleniumCommands.waitClickById(ASSESSMENTNEXTPAGEBUTTON);
    try { Thread.sleep(500); } catch (InterruptedException ie) { ie.getMessage(); }
    pageTitle = SeleniumCommands.findElementsByXpath(PAGETITLE);
    try { Thread.sleep(500); } catch (InterruptedException ie) { ie.getMessage(); }
    System.out.println(pageTitle.get(0));
    if (pageTitle.size() > 0) {
        if (pageTitle.get(0).getText().equals("Assessment"))
            mobileAssessmentPage();
    }
}
```

For some reason, on the page where I know it should return an empty list (since the page title should not be found), the two exceptions I keep getting are "StaleElementReferenceException" (or something like that) or "Element is no longer attached to the DOM".  Is there a better way to go about this?

I am trying to make the method dynamic by calling itself for every page where it is needed; unfortunately, the Selenium methods don't make this convenient since they return an error if they can't find an element instead of a `Boolean` or `-1` or even a `null WebElement` or something logical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [selenium docs](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp):

> A stale element reference exception is thrown in one of two cases, the
>   first being more common than the second:
>
> The element has been deleted entirely. The element is no longer
>   attached to the DOM.

The latter include cases where an element is deleted and replaced by a new one with almost the same attributes and DOM location. Any JS library might be doing that in reaction to clicking one of the elements, so the rest of the elements get "stale".

## How can you avoid this?

One solution that I used is to not keep a reference to each of the elements but find each of the single elements just before clicking it. As the elements share a selector, you can first get the count and then get them by subindex. Adapting your example:

```
public static void mobileAssessmentPage() {
    int q = SeleniumCommands.findElementsByCss(ASSESSMENTANSWER).count();

    List<WebElement> pageTitle;

    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
        WebElement element = SeleniumCommands.findElementsByCss(ASSESSMENTANSWER)[i];
        element.click();
    }

    SeleniumCommands.waitClickById(ASSESSMENTNEXTPAGEBUTTON);
    try { Thread.sleep(500); } catch (InterruptedException ie) { ie.getMessage(); }
    pageTitle = SeleniumCommands.findElementsByXpath(PAGETITLE);
    try { Thread.sleep(500); } catch (InterruptedException ie) { ie.getMessage(); }
    System.out.println(pageTitle.get(0));
    if (pageTitle.size() > 0)
        if (pageTitle.get(0).getText().equals("Assessment"))
            mobileAssessmentPage();
}
```

If that's not enough (and many times it's not), you might want to use some waiting or retry in that `for`, something like:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {            
        WebElement element = SeleniumCommands.findElementsByCss(ASSESSMENTANSWER)[i];
        element.click();
        Thread.sleep(200);
    }
```

or:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {            
        try {
            WebElement element = SeleniumCommands.findElementsByCss(ASSESSMENTANSWER)[i];
            element.click();
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            Thread.sleep(200); // optional, but just to be safe...
            WebElement element = SeleniumCommands.findElementsByCss(ASSESSMENTANSWER)[i];
            element.click();
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but even with this method I still do receive an "Element is no longer attached to the DOM" StaleReferenceException.

I have to head out for now, but I will be back tomorrow to continue troubleshooting this error.

Comment: It can still be that as a side effect of the `click`, an update is made in an async manner, so between the next `findElementsByCss` and the `click` you can get that error... You should play adding a bit of sleep before the `findElementsByCss`... just to be sure, the error appears always on the `click`?

Comment: It's sometimes unavoidable to use a bit of manual waiting here and there, or retries, when working with a dynamic page with selenium. I'll edit the answer to show where I would do the wait and/or the retry

Comment: The problem never happened here before. It is only once I started locating the title of the page.

Comment: Ok... well, rewinding a bit, you should first try to find a smaller case that reproduces the error... there's nothing that you can remove or simplify from your example that still makes the error to occur? For example, the error appears if you just click on the first of the elements instead of on all of them? If you remove all the clicking on the elements found by `ASSESSMENTANSWER`, does the error show up? If that's the case, I was focusing my answer on the wrong part of the code...

Comment: Hi @nberger, in response to your last comment, I can't really test that very easily since, in order to advance pages, I have to answer all questions. If I only click some or just the first, I can't get to a page where the if conditional will fail and then produce my stale element exception. The stale element exception ONLY happens when the if conditions at the bottom fails

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The reason this was occurring was that when I went to the next page to see if it met the conditions, the pageTitle still held the values from the previous page thanks to race conditions.  I needed to initialize and instantiate and add a wait after going to the next page to give the page enough time to load before creating the object.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should not use Thread sleep! This bad practice for production tests. You should also use page-object pattern (it's very useful).

**About your actual question:** Elements need some time for attaching to parent elements.  For example: when a developer used animation, or an application generates difficult user interfaces, then this process need some time for rendering.  Otherwise the element will be attached whenever the application  completes some task(s). You just need to wait when element will be attached. Webdriver has special classes and methods for this cases:

```
 WebElement webElement = new WebDriverWait(driver(), 3).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("some css celector"))); //this code wait untill element will be attached about 3 seconds
webElement.click() //now you clicking on element
```

You can use many useful methods in the [ExpectedConditions](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) class.  Remember, you should use `Thread.sleep()` very seldom, and only if you don't have another option. Good luck.

Comment: I do appreciate your critique on my use of thread sleeps but that is not part of my question. I am quite aware of the better methods to use. I go back and refactor as necessary.

Comment: If you need boolean checking: new WebDriverWait(driver(), 35).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return driver().findElements(By.id("someId")).size() > 0;
            }
        });//wait 35 secons when we will be attached some element with id "someId"

Comment: How would be that bad to use Thread.sleep if that's what selenium will use... `WebDriverWait` is a `FluentWait` which uses a `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Sleeper` to do `Thread.sleep` [in this line of code](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Sleeper.java#28). Yes, you should try hard to not use `Thread.sleep` and use the plethora of waits from Selenium. But given there's not enough information on which wait to use here to be sure the element will not be stale by the time the `click` is done, `Thread.sleep` is a valid option